# .net 4 Architecture: MVC, WCF Data Services, Repository Pattern, Entity Framework come together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services, odata

I have the luxury of starting from scratch with all the latest a greatest .net 4 bits & bobs. My app must support different clients including an MVC Website, iphone App, andriod App & other websites

My application processes quite a bit of spatial data and will need to rely on caching because it exposes geo RSS feeds to allow areas to be rendered as polygons on Bing Maps Ajax 7.

I know I want to use all the above technologies, BUT I'm not yet 100% sure how they all come together.

Sadly E.F. 4 doesn't support spatial data types OR SqlDependecy cache invalidation. SO for some of my data access I've decided to fall back on ADO .net 2 SqlCommands / Stored Procedures (I also think it's going to be worthwhile having SQL Spatial functions pre-compiled and occurring inside of SQL Server).

Hence from my current understanding, here is what I'm thinking:

1) I'll have an .edmx which does Data Access for types with no spatial properties. I will then have Repositories for those types which talk the the .edmx and return POCO objects (using the EF4 Poco Templates).

2) I'll have repositories with hand written ADO .net 2 code for the types with spatial bits.

3) I'll have Service Layer classes (hand written) that encapsulate the repositories (not know how they're implemented or what they are talking to). Here I'll implement security and business logic.

4) I'll have a WCF Data Service (.net 4) deployed in a separate application that exposes the Service layer as OData for the different clients to consume.

5) My MVC as will talk to my WCF Data Service layer from controller code.

6) Other clients will talk to the WCF Data Service layer and deal with the OData they way they wish.

Does that make sense? Using OData for invoking business operations instead of just CRUD? Are there major road blocks and challengers with security and identity over Odata?

Also is it going to be too onerous and should I be looking for some type of hybrid for better performance & less code, like talking directly with (3) from my web app and breaking the layer cake?

Comment: My concerns about OData Security & Identity were answer by this presentation: http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/a32fdeb8-c878-4bf8-8d5c-6a56309b525c

Answer (score 3):

Tough love here.

Don't BFUD ( big up front design ) your application if you don't understand the technologies you want to work with.  You'll do more harm than good.  Using the most popular patterns != success.

Start small, spike out some tiny pieces and grow from there.

Comment: I'm already a week and a half into coding my app (spatial repositories have been built). I'm know about EF4 because I've rapidly built a DAL using it before on another project (and know the caching, spatial limitations). The new thing for me is the OData / WCF Data Service, but I'm very aware of the requirement for other client types... I guess I'll just have to play with it all and learn by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with below that sounds like a fair amount of unknowns in the architecting of your system -keep it simple as much as possible - having 2 separate DALs (ODATA and your custom one) is a recipe for code maintainability hell. -you may want to skip the odata part.

your Parts 2&3, 6 seems a bit iffy if your clients need access to the spatial data types concurrently with the ODATA service  REST data. not sure how you can solve that

I will say that ODATA can be accessed by .NET client apps very easily, and there is support for client access via Javascript, Java (see RESTLET) -its great from my limited experience with it for .NET service and .NET clients -haven't used it yet on non .NET clients

Good Luck.. I'd like to know how this all turns out.

Comment: I'm exposing the Spacial Data types using a separate WCF Service that returns GeoRss that is called using jQuery.ajax and consumed by javascript on the client.